Is my stepper motor driver causing me current issues or is it me?
I've been using a Pancake Bipolar Stepper Motor for a project and STSPIN220 as the driver, but I've been randomly having a lot of current issues causing my motor to jitter.
My project has been running fine for many months but out of nowhere before I even run my code, just having it plugged into my power supply while it's on will cause the motor to jitter and even while running on full step it will jitter as it goes.
I noticed that the current it's pulling has been really low compared to before. When it pulls around 0.30-0.60 A at 5V on my power supply, it will jitter, but occasionally, it will pull 0.90 A, and it will stop jittering and run smoothly.
The Vref on the driver is correct, but when I measured the current of one of the motor's coils, it was very low for a full step, even considering other factors that could be lowering it. So I raised the Vref by 50 mV, and it was working well for a while (pulling around 0.90 A), but it keeps going back to pulling 0.30-0.70 A and jittering.
I tried a new STSPIN220, but eventually, I will get the same issues again, so I'm thinking of trying a whole different driver. Looking at what Polulu recommends, I'm thinking of using DRV8834 as a replacement but I'm not exactly sure if it's the right fit.
Am I doing something wrong or should I just try a different driver? I included the notes I wrote when I was trying to verify the driver in case I did anything wrong but I'm not sure anymore since it was running fine but a long time.


Please show both the schematic and a picture of the completed circuit so that we can follow the connections. Most likely there’s something wrong with how the circuit is physically laid out. Make clear picture of the breadboard, or if it’s a PCB, show both layers clearly.

The STSPIN220 driver obviously is a working product so most likely you damage them by overstressing them relative to the datasheet specs. This over stress can be caused by poor layout and/or insufficient design of the surrounding circuitry. That’s why, to be of any use, the question needs those details. Use the edit function to add them in. Images can be directly copy-pasted from paint, Photos app, EDA program; etc.

I can send a pic when I’m home but it’s just weird because why would it also happen to all 3 drivers when 2 of them are barely used

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica  btw ty for responding and the help! I really appreciate it!
This a link of my circuit and block diagram (sorry I didn't make a schematic yet) : https://imgur.com/a/Cabxbtl
It's just weird because it has been working for over 2 years so I'm not sure what could've happened to cause this since the only changes are just me testing out different codes I wrote in order to change the directions of the motor
